# Guice: Using parameter in Module (JndiIntegration)

Tags: jndi, guice

I've a module like this

```
public class JNDITransactionModule implements Module{

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(TransactionManager.class)
              .toProvider(
                   JndiIntegration.fromJndi(
                      TransactionManager.class, 
                      "URI TO TRANSACTION MANAGER"))
              .in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }
}
```

Well, I think my question is easy, but... how can I parametrize the "URI TO TRANSACTION MANAGER" value??

I mean, something like this

```
public class JNDITransactionModule implements Module{

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
           Properties props = getProperties("transaction.properties");
           Names.bindProperties(binder, props);

        binder.install(new TransactionModule());
        binder.bind(TransactionManager.class)
              .toProvider(
                   JndiIntegration.fromJndi(
                      TransactionManager.class, 
                      "get @Named('transaction.jndi-uri')"))
              .in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }
}
```

and a configuration file called transaction.properties which contains this

```
  transaction.jndi-uri = URI TO TRANSACTION MANAGER
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a separate provider or a *@Provides* method. The following should work:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
TransactionManager provideTransactionManager(@Named("transaction.jndi-uri") String uri) {
    return JndiIntegration.fromJndi(TransactionManager.class, uri).get();
}
```