# Getting an @Resource into my Guice Module

Tags: jboss7.x, guice, infinispan

I've seen various bits and pieces, but I'm either approaching this wrong or a bit short on my understanding on Guice.  I'm trying to modify/extend this [cache4guice Infinispan Module](https://code.google.com/p/cache4guice/source/browse/trunk/src/org/cache4guice/adapters/infinispan/InfinispanCacheModule.java)  so that it can access the JBoss embedded module, and ultimately named caches within the selected cache container.

So, we have my standalone.xml with the following:

```
<cache-container name="InfinispanCacheModule" default-cache="cache1" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/container/mycachecontainer>
<local-cache name="cache1">
    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="1000"/>
    <expiration max-idle="50000"/>
    <file-store preload="true" passivation="true" purge="false"/>
</local-cache>
<local-cache name="cache2">
    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="500"/>
    <expiration max-idle="20000"/>
    <file-store preload="true" passivation="false" purge="false"/>
</local-cache>
```

I've modified the @Cached annotation to allow a cachedName argument to be optionally included.  The idea being you could use this for a default cache:

```
@Cached
public someMethod(String someArg) {...}
```

This for accessing cache2 and beyond...

```
@Cached(cacheName="cache2")
public someOtherMethod(String someArg) {...}
```

The only examples that I've found that would seem to allow me to access things is such a fashion would be using the jndi resource, such as in this page - ttp://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/9781590599976/guice-recipes/integrating_jndi

Which leads me to try something like this:

```
public class InfinispanCacheModule extends CacheModule {
...
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // bind naming context to the default InitialContext
        bind(Context.class).to(InitialContext.class);

        bind(CacheContainer.class).toProvider(JndiIntegration.fromJndi(CacheContainer.class, "java:jboss/infinispan/container/mycachecontainer"));

        bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Cached.class), new CacheInterceptor(this));        
    }
```

Additionally, from the posts here and elsewhere, it seems that I might want to use an @Provides method - along these lines: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8999548/880884
[Guice: is it possible to inject modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504555/guice-is-it-possible-to-inject-modules)

So, now we get into specifics, if we look at the original InfinispanModule, the idea is for me to either pass in a CacheManager on module creation, or create one within the module somehow.

```
public class MyGuiceFactory {
private static final Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(
new SomeGuiceModule(), 
new InfinispanCacheModule(---- what goes here? -----)
);
public static Injector getInjector() {
    return inj;
}
}
```

Similar question:
[Spring, Infinispan and JBoss 7 integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858624/spring-infinispan-and-jboss-7-integration/15001115#15001115)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working I just used normal context and lookup.  I placed the following method in my Guice Factory, then passed the CacheContainer to the InfinispanCacheModule via a new constructor.

```
public static CacheContainer getCacheContainer() {
    org.infinispan.manager.CacheContainer container = null;
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        container = (CacheContainer) ctx
                .lookup("java:jboss/infinispan/container/mycache");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.getCause();
    }
    return container;
}
```

From there I was able to use a 'cacheName' annotation parameter in the Injector, then reach back to the InfinispanCacheModule's getCache(String cacheName) method. If you want me to share more code repsond to this thread and I will post more details.